# How does this linked list partitioning algorithm work?

Tags: java, linked-list, partition, correctness

I'm reading right now the book *Cracking the Coding Interview*, which presents a linked list partition problem:

> Given a linked list and a value x, partition a linked list around a value x, such that all nodes less than x come before all nodes greater than or equal to x.

Assume that the linked list is not empty.

[The solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partitioning-linked-list-around-given-value-dont-care-making-elements-list-stable/) is taken from the website GeeksForGeeks, and is identical to the second solution offered in the book CTCI:

> ```
> // Function to make a new list  
> // (using the existing nodes) and  
> // return head of new list.  
> static Node partition(Node head, int x)  
> {  
>     /* Let us initialize start and tail nodes of new list */
>     Node tail = head;  
>   
>     // Now iterate original list and connect nodes  
>     Node curr = head;  
>     while (curr != null)  
>     {  
>         Node next = curr.next;  
>         if (curr.data < x)  
>         {  
>             /* Insert node at head. */
>             curr.next = head;  
>             head = curr;  
>         }  
>   
>         else // Append to the list of greater values  
>         {  
>             /* Insert node at tail. */
>             tail.next = curr;  
>             tail = curr;  
>         }  
>         curr = next;  
>     }  
>     tail.next = null;  
>   
>     // The head has changed, so we need  
>     // to return it to the user.  
>     return head;  
> }
> ```

I don't understand this solution. How does this algorithm work? Why is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try to think about like so:

Lets say this is our linked list `(0) -> (1) -> (2) -> (-1) -> (1) -> (-5)`  (obviously linked lists don't look like this but for our example)

And `x = 0`

We do `next = curr.next` so that we don't "lose" the next node

\ I'm going to mark *head and ^tail

Now we look at (0) it doesn't matter if it's smaller than x (bcs its both head and tail) so its pointer is turned at itself

```
[*^(0)<  ] [  (1) -> (2) -> (-1) -> (1) -> (-5) ]
```

Now we look at (1) its not smaller than x either so (0) is pointed at it and it becomes ^tail

`[ *(0) -> ^(1)< ] [ (2) -> (-1) -> (1) -> (-5) ]` (the two lists are attached but lets imagine their not)

Same thing happens with (2) ^tail which is- (1) is pointed at it

```
[ *(0) -> (1) -> ^(2)<  ] [  (-1) -> (1) -> (-5) ]
```

Now we look at (-1) however this time it is smaller than x so its set to point at *head and then set to *head

```
[ *(-1) -> (0) -> (1) -> ^(2)<  ] [  (1) -> (-5) ]
```

And so on:

```
[ *(-1) -> (0) -> (1) -> (2) -> ^(1)<  ] [ (-5) ]

[ *(-5) -> (-1) -> (0) -> (1) -> (2) -> ^(1)<  ] [ ]
```